# Trying to export a panda DataFrame to CSV, but it denies permission

Tags: python, pandas

So, I'm triyng to export a data frame with data on the recent pandemic:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Giorno': time_period,
    'Infetti': infected,
    'Morti': dead,
    'Guariti': recovered})
```

where `time_period`, `infected`, `dead` and `recovered` are lists. When I use the command

```
df.to_csv(r'D:\Python\COVID-19\COVID-19.py', header = df.keys(), index = None, sep = ' ', mode = 'a')
```

this is the error it returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Coding\Python\COVID-19\COVID-19.py", line 96, in <module>
    df.to_csv(r'D:\Coding\Python\COVID-19', header = df.keys(), index = None, sep = ' ', mode = 'a')
  File "C:\Users\39351\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3204, in to_csv
    formatter.save()
  File "C:\Users\39351\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\csvs.py", line 188, in save
    compression=dict(self.compression_args, method=self.compression),
  File "C:\Users\39351\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 428, in get_handle
    f = open(path_or_buf, mode, encoding=encoding, newline="")
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'D:\\Coding\\Python\\COVID-19'
```

I have tried running the script from the command prompt (opened as admin) but it raises the exact same error. I've tried a test script that writes `a` fifteen times in a newly created text file, and the test script works fine editing the file when it already exists (done this just to see if Python creates new files in this folder) and everything is fine. Am I doing something wrong with the original code?

Comment: You're trying to convert a python file to csv? D:\Python\COVID-19\COVID-19.py

Comment: Oh my Lord, sorry for the mistake. I'm not trying to convert the file, I pasted the wrong string in StackOverflow, I'll correct it.

Comment: I bet you the file is open :) Try closing it!

Comment: @DavidErickson Is there a "I love you" option near the "Flag this comment" option?

Comment: Happens to me all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Try typing any name in the pd.to_csv(), without incluing the full path of the file. That will save the file in the folder of the script. Also, make sure to include ".csv" at the end of that name.

If it works, you can either try the full path or a relative path.

Hope I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Change the backslash to slash :
**'D:/Python/COVID-19/COVID-19.py'**